# Вывести дату и время в таблице QTableView

Tags: qt, c++

В базе данных есть поля типа text и int. В последнем хранится timestamp.
Не могу понять, как можно вывести в таблице дату и время на основе данной временной отметки.
Сейчас выводится только само значение timestamp...

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
model->setQuery("SELECT text, timestamp FROM notes");
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Text"));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Created"));

QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(model);
view->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток! Если я правильно Вас понял, то QSqlQueryModel интерпретирует timestamp как простое число. Вы можете пронаследовать свой класс от `QSqlQueryModel` и перекрыть в нем метод `data()` (подробно о том как это делается можно найти в документации) и реализовать его так чтобы он возвращал `QDateTime` (например использовать статический метод `QDateTime::fromTime_t()`.