# QDateEdit в QTableView

Tags: qt

Как заставить **QTableView** использовать **QDateEdit** для столбца? В ячейках столбца хранятся timestamp-ы. Нужно отображение датой и возможность редактирования с помощью QDateEdit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо написать своего [наследника QItemDelegate](http://prog-master.com/qt-qitemdelegate/), он довольно простой - нужно будет всего лишь переопределить несколько методов, а именно создать и вернуть QDateEdit в методе createEditor, вставить в него дату внутри метода setEditorData и вернуть ее в модель с помощью метода setModelData.  Конкретно для QDateEdit я такого не делал, но когда-то делал что-то подобное для [комбобокса](https://github.com/aknew/CoinsVariationBase/blob/7ebf1cfcf17f68682a0b6ae810dd9c4e628ed923/comboboxdelegate.cpp)

Comment: Хорошо, это помогло (при редактировании). А как заставить QTableView отображать time_t как дату? Менять значения на стадии получения из БД?

Answer (score 1):

Такой вопрос уже задавался: [Вывести дату и время в таблице QTableView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196317/c-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-qtableview)

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно было.